# Online Tool for truncating lines (each line having a maximum length of xxx)

Tags: string, text

I have been searching everywhere for an online tool doing a simple but crucial thing:
Truncating each line in a document after x number of characters (output: each line having a maximum length of xx characters).

I would be very happy if someone could give me the URL for such tool!!

Example:

Document has 3 lines
It should truncate each line after 20 characters

INPUT:

- Xxx xxx xxxxxx. Xxxxxx xxxxx, xxx xxx xxxx.
- Xx xxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xx.
- Xxxxxxx.

OUTPUT:

- Xxx xxx xxxxxx. Xxxx
- Xx xxx xxx xxxx xxxx
- Xxxxxxx.

What I want to find is: 1) an online tool where I paste the original text in one box, 2) enter the desired maximimum number of characters per line, 3) click on a button, 4) find the result in another box/or the same box.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why does this need to be an "online tool"?  Would not something like [`cut -c 1-20`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28Unix%29) do the trick?

Comment: Thanks eggyal! No it does't have to be an online tool, but the problem is that I am not a programmer... Is there any similar downloadable app that can be used on a PC or MAC (preferably MAC)?

Comment: Since it has a BSD kernel, OS X comes installed with `cut`.

Answer (score 1):

In OS X Terminal:

- If you have the input data in a file at `/path/to/file.txt`:

  ```
  $ cut -c 1-20 /path/to/file.txt
  Xxx xxx xxxxxx. Xxxx
  Xx xxx xxx xxxx xxxx
  Xxxxxxx.
  ```
- If you wish to enter the data interactively:

  ```
  $ cut -c 1-20 <<EOF
  > Xxx xxx xxxxxx. Xxxxxx xxxxx, xxx xxx xxxx.
  > Xx xxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xx.
  > Xxxxxxx.
  > EOF
  Xxx xxx xxxxxx. Xxxx
  Xx xxx xxx xxxx xxxx
  Xxxxxxx.
  ```

Comment: Wow! I actually got it to work!!! Thanks a million! May the Internet gods grant you a prosperous life! Thanks!